# How To Make KinematicBody2D Move By Drag in One Direction in GDScript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I wanted to create a game similar to this (Slyway), but I had a problem with the child's movement, so I don't know what to use to do the movement during the draw. Is InputEventScreenTouch Or InputEventScreenDrag, all I come up with is this code that isn't working

```
    extends KinematicBody2D

var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var direction = Vector2.ZERO
var speed = 200

func input(event):
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        if event.ispressed():
            direction.x -= 1

func physicsprocess(delta):
    if velocity.length() == 0:
    _input(event)
velocity = Vector2.ZERO
velocity += direction * speed
velocity = moveand_slide (velocity)
```

Comment: You have a few typos in your code (`_input`, `_physics_process`, `is_pressed`, `move_and_slide`), and that is disregarding the indentation (edit: which is relevant in GDScript).